# MemoryError in python 2.7

Tags: python, memory

I m running a python program that consume a large memory, I have 64bit windows 7 OS and  4 GB of  RAM, still when the private bytes for my program reaches about 1.5GB it genearates the MemoryError. Is there any solution to get more RAM for the program ? or please help me through other solutions

Comment: Are you using 64-bit Python?

Comment: MemoryError is caused by failure of underlying architecture (the C 'malloc' function) so your OS is limiting memory usage. Have you tried to optimize your program? What does your code? Try to post here

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not tried it but I think this should help. Just try to increase the virtual memory size and see the effect if it resolve.[Here is the explanation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/preventing-low-memory-problems#1TC=windows-7). Give it a go if you have time to test.

To change the virtual memory size follow [these instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/change-virtual-memory-size#1TC=windows-7):

> 1. Open System by clicking the **Start** button, right-clicking **Computer**, and then clicking **Properties**.
> 2. In the left pane, click **Advanced system settings**. If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the
>      password or provide confirmation.
> 3. On the **Advanced** tab, under **Performance**, click **Settings**.
> 4. Click the **Advanced** tab, and then, under **Virtual memory**, click **Change**.
> 5. Clear the **Automatically manage paging file size for all drives** check box.
> 6. Under **Drive [Volume Label]**, click the drive that contains the paging file you want to change.
> 7. Click **Custom size**, type a new size in megabytes in the **Initial size (MB)** or **Maximum size (MB)** box, click **Set**, and then click **OK**.